# Animacion de SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

hasta ahora he logrado esto con los keyframes, es lo que quiero, pero ahora solo me queda el problema de que se acelera mucho o relentiza al final , la idea es que sea constante para que funcione como loader de una web y una app, no se si es algo en el keyframe o falta alguna propiedad. muchas gracias por la ayuda que me den.

```css
body {
 background-color: #3F82F1;
 width: 100%;
}
#estaciona{
 width:70%;
 height:70%;
}
.cont {
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-top: 100px;
}
.cont1 {
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: absolute;
 text-align:center;
}
.st2 {
    fill: none;
    stroke: none;
    stroke-width: 29;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    }
.st2, .st3{
    animation-name: dash;
    animation-duration: 8s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    /* animation-direction: normal; */
    animation-delay: 1s;
}
@keyframes dash{
 0%{
 /*stroke-dasharray:0;*/
 stroke-dashoffset: 5000;
 /*animation-direction:normal;*/
 }
 100%{
    stroke-dasharray: 1560;
    stroke-dashoffset: 30000;
    stroke: #fff;
    /* animation-direction: alternate-reverse; */
    stroke-linecap: round;
    /* animation-iteration-count: infinite; */
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
 
 <div class="cont1">
  <svg version="1.1"
  id="estaciona" image-rendering="optimizeQuality" text-rendering="geometricPrecision" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 483 552"
  style="enable-background:new 0 0 483 552;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:#fff; stroke:none;}/*fondo circulo E*/
 .st1{fill:#3F82F1;} /*letra E*/
 .st2{fill:none;stroke:none;stroke-width:29;stroke-miterlimit:10;} /*Linea superior*/
 .st3{fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:none;}/*punta redonda*/
</style>
<g>
 <path class="st0" d="M240.6,89.3c-76,0-137.6,61.6-137.6,137.6s61.6,137.6,137.6,137.6s137.6-61.6,137.6-137.6
  S316.6,89.3,240.6,89.3z"/>
 <polygon class="st1" points="294.1,140.8 294.1,170 224.6,170 224.6,211 294.1,211 294.1,240 224.6,240 224.6,280.7 294.1,280.7 
  294.1,309.8 187.9,309.8 187.9,140.8  "/>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <path class="st2" d="M375.3,370.6C497.5,262.5,423.2,36.8,248,36.8C46.3,36.8,0,257.3,94.6,357.1
   c84.8,89.5,160.6,162.1,160.6,162.1"/>
  <g>
   <!--<path class="st3" d="M384.8,381c-6,5-15,4.2-20-1.9s-4.2-15,1.9-20c6-5,15-4.2,20,1.9C391.7,367.1,390.9,376,384.8,381z"/>-->
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>

 </div>




</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He simplificado algo tu código. Espero que te guste el resultado.

La animación es prácticamente la misma, solo le he añadido una función temporizador: `animation-timing-function:ease-in;` y dura 5 segundos en lugar de 8

```css
body {
 background-color: #3F82F1;
}
#estaciona{
 height:100vh;
  display:block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.contorno{
  stroke-dasharray: 1323.9, 1323.9;
  stroke-dashoffset:  1323.9;

  animation-name: dash;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function:ease-in;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
@keyframes dash{
 0%{
 stroke-dashoffset: -1323.9;
 }
 100%{
  stroke-dashoffset: 1323.9;
 }
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="estaciona" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 483 552">
<style type="text/css">
 circle{fill:#fff; stroke:none;}/*fondo circulo E*/
 .E{fill:#3F82F1;} /*letra E*/
 .contorno{fill:none;stroke-width:29;stroke:white; stroke-width:29; stroke-linecap:round; } /*Linea superior*/
 
</style>

<circle cx="240.6" cy="226.9" r="137.6" />
<polygon class="E" points="294.1,140.8 294.1,170 224.6,170 224.6,211 294.1,211 294.1,240 224.6,240 224.6,280.7 294.1,280.7 294.1,309.8 187.9,309.8 187.9,140.8  "/>
<path class="contorno" id="gabi"  d="M375.3,370.6A194.028,194.028 0 1 0 94.6,357.1L255,519"/>
     
</svg>
```

Si te preguntas cómo he calculado el valor para `stroke-dashoffset` (1323.9) he utilizado el método `getTotalLength()` que devuelve la longitud de un trazado SVG.

Comment: Wow, mucha gracias chamo!, esta genial, ese era el resultado que estaba buscando., gracias por enseñarme.

Comment: una ultima pregunta, si quiero que haga lo mismo, pero una vez llegue al final ambas puntas se devuelva y crezca de regreso pero de derecha a izq. y asi dando a entender como autos que entran y salen. ya que es un logo fiscal de autos.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta. Prueba añadir ` animation-direction: alternate;`en el CSS. A lo mejor es esto lo que quieres. Si no lo es, por favor haz otra pregunta con más detalles.

Comment: esa era, muchas gracias, ahora animare la E del centro, gracias.